# How to use a FnMut argument in a closure without moving it or requiring Copy?

Tags: rust, closures

I'm still a little confused on how the `Fn`-`FnMut`-`FnOnce` thing works with other traits. I want to eliminate the `Copy` constraint from the following function for traversing a tree structure.

```
pub fn for_each<F>(&mut self, mut f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&mut Tree<T>) + Copy,
{
    self.children.iter_mut().for_each(|c| c.for_each(f));
    f(self);
}
```

The reason for this is that I am trying to pass a closure that modifies an outside variable to `for_each` and the `Copy` prevents that (`E0277`). However, when I get rid of the `Copy`, I get the following error message:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `f`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/tree.rs:34:58
   |
30 |     pub fn for_each<F>(&mut self, mut f: F)
   |                                   ----- captured outer variable
...
34 |         self.children.iter_mut().for_each(|c| c.for_each(f));
   |                                                          ^ move occurs because `f` has type `F`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `f`
  --> src/tree.rs:35:9
   |
30 |     pub fn for_each<F>(&mut self, mut f: F)
   |                                   ----- move occurs because `f` has type `F`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
34 |         self.children.iter_mut().for_each(|c| c.for_each(f));
   |                                           ---            - variable moved due to use in closure
   |                                           |
   |                                           value moved into closure here
35 |         f(self);
   |         ^ value borrowed here after move
   |
help: consider further restricting this bound
   |
32 |         F: FnMut(&mut Tree<T>) + Copy,
   |                                ^^^^^^

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
```

How can I solve this issue? I'm also open to turning this into an iterator if that makes it easier.

Comment: In the future please try to create a [mre], so that people don't have to guess at the code context and can test their code before answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is, that `for_each` takes ownership of `f`.

This means, that once you call `c.for_each(f)`, you loose ownership of `f`, thus you cannot use `f` later.
In order to fix this, you could change the `for_each` function to instead take a reference, so you can pass it along like this

```rust
pub fn for_each<F>(&mut self, f: &mut F)
where
    F: FnMut(&mut Tree<T>),
{
    // Only a reference is passed into for_each here
    self.children.iter_mut().for_each(|c| c.for_each(f));
    // f can be used again, as reference is reborrowed implicitly
    f(self);
}
```

Or you could also (if possible) move the call to `f` up a line like this

```rust
pub fn for_each<F>(&mut self, mut f: F)
where
    F: FnMut(&mut Tree<T>),
{
    // f is used, but ownership is kept
    f(self);
    // ownership of f can now be transferred, as there is no further use of it
    self.children.iter_mut().for_each(|c| c.for_each(f));
}
```

Comment: I can't use the second solution because I need the ordering of the calls to be the way it is now. Adding the `&` to the type causes type annotations needed errors where I used `for_each`; I'll accept once I figure those out.

Comment: Got it, just had to add `&mut` before all the closures. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please test your code before answering, I think I have fixed it, but the original would not have worked at all. (Of course this would have been easier if OP had created a [mre])